# Op type not registered 'SentencepieceEncodeSparse' in binary

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I had deployed a model which used a tfhub model to tensorflow-serving using a docker.

**Here is the tfhub model contained in my model:**

https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/1

**Here is the command to run the docker**

```
docker run -t --rm -p 8501:8501 \
    -v "/docker_dir/model_tf_serving:/models/mymodel" \
    -e MODEL_NAME=mymodel \
    tensorflow/serving &
```

**Error happened:**

```
Not found: Op type not registered 'SentencepieceEncodeSparse' in binary running on c5e507bf091b. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) `tf.contrib.resampler` should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.
```

**So is there a way to  fix this?**

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you're still having that problem but it worked for me to

1. download that module with `pip install tensorflow-text`
2. type `import tensorflow_text`

since that tf-hub modules depend on that package.

Comment: How are you doing this in `tensorflow-serving`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the sentencepiece module for TensorFlow:

```
pip install sentencepiece tf-sentencepiece
```

Comment: This dosent solve the problem! The problem here is that the ops form tf-centerpice are no registered in the save_model.pb. I'm trying to find a way to do it

Comment: They're not registered because it is not loading the tf-sentencepiece modules that are responsible for registering it.

Comment: That is Right Tarantula, however to install the sentencepiece with pip dosen't work for tensorflow serving, since it uses only a saved_model.pb file.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this? I am getting same error while trying to deploy on AzureML: Op type not registered 'SentencepieceOp' in binary running..

Answer (score 0):

There is an instruction from the official hub page how to use the model with tensorflow=2.
https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/2

Worked for me.

```
!pip3 install tensorflow_text>=2.0.0rc0

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text
embed = tf.saved_model.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual/2")
```

Comment: Yes, it does work when you use it directly, But it dosen't work for tensorflow serving,