# How run TensorFlow model with ML.NET

Tags: python, c#, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, ml.net

I have code that in C# runs a tensorflow model with ML.NET. But when I run it, it throws

"`Unhandled exception. Tensorflow.TensorflowException: Op type not registered 'SentencepieceOp' in binary running on f-desktop. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered in the binary running in this process. Note that if you are loading a saved graph which used ops from tf.contrib, accessing (e.g.) tf.contrib.resampler should be done before importing the graph, as contrib ops are lazily registered when the module is first accessed.`"

I found that installing tensor_flow text will help ([Op type not registered 'SentencepieceEncodeSparse' in binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56862189/op-type-not-registered-sentencepieceencodesparse-in-binary)), but, suddenly I now need to "import tensorflow_text".

I have a folder, named "universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large_3", with model there's some files and folders: assets (empty folder), saved_model.pb, variables/variables.data-00000-of-00001 and variables/variables.index. 
I don't see where I can "import tensorflow_text".

Code in C#

```
using  Microsoft.ML.TensorFlow;
using  Microsoft.ML;

// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
var context  = new MLContext();
var tensorFlowModel = context.Model.LoadTensorFlowModel("universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large_3");
```